# Microcontroller Oscillator Layout for ESD immunity

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, layout, esd

I have a small portable USB device failing ESD immunity.  It's a two layer board with a solid ground plane on the bottom. I have diode protected inputs, and there's a TVS on the USB connector, and I'm wondering if I need to think about discharges to the ground plane and how that would affect the oscillator.

I've seen [recommendations](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-8128-Best-Practices-for-the-PCB-Layout-of-Oscillators_ApplicationNote_AVR186.pdf) for a ground island for the oscillator, but I'm not 
entirely sure if I've implemented them correctly.  I was hoping some wiser individuals might be able to give me some feedback.

**Some Questions that Come to Mind**

1. Should the decoupling capacitor be connected to the crystal?
2. Should the island extend upward to cover the oscillator signal
   traces?
3. Is the island big enough?
4. Is making the island going to make any difference at all?

I would love to hear any feedback that would help me produce more robust designs.  Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Failing immunity - why do you think it's the oscillator/crystal?

Comment: It could very well not be related to the oscillator, but I still think it deserves some thought.  Often the device will just reset itself after an ESD event, but sometimes it hangs and I have to disconnect and reconnect the USB.

Comment: It would be good to see the whole schematic/layout to identify possible causes. Assuming it's the crystal, may be very well be a shot in the dark.

Comment: Another thing, how are the ESD events happening, how are you triggering them? By touching the board, or by plugging the USB connector in and out?

Comment: The events are being delivered by an ESD simulator on the ground connection of an external input.  I'm not really worried about finding the cause of the failures.  For me this question is more about best practices with oscillator layout.

Comment: You should name your nets something useful, right now it's impossible to tell what `N$13`, `N$9`, `N$8` are and if they are interferring. For example if `N$13` is a high speed clock, like EREF (Ethernet Reference Clock), this can be a problem. I assume `N$8` is actually +3V3, but I can't tell because it would seem your oscillator should have a power source as well...

Comment: No high speed and absolutely no issues during normal operation.  N$8 is +3v3.  N$13 is the microcontroller's RESET pin.

Comment: @RobertJonkman So the question is basically "how should I lay out an oscillator?" and the ESD part is irrelevant?

Comment: Shouldn't there be loading capacitors with that crystal?